# PHP and related staff installation

Tags: php, lamp, phpmyadmin, php7

I am going to install LAMP. In this regard I am going to run below command.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php php-pear php-fpm php-dev php-zip php-curl php-xmlrpc php-gd php-mysql php-mbstring php-xml mysql-server php-mysql php-dom phpmyadmin composer
```

Is this a correct command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what distro you are working on, but supposingly its ubuntu you can follow the steps in this link [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) .. and change the version of the distro if you are working on a different version .. but if you are working on a non(debian/ubuntu) based distros just change the package manger in the command and it will be almost the same steps.

Step 1: Install Apache and Allow in Firewall

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"
```

Step 2: Install MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Step 3: Install PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
```

then modify the way that Apache serves files when a directory is requested.
To do this, type this command to open the dir.conf file in a text editor with root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

It will look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

We want to move the PHP index file highlighted above to the first position after the DirectoryIndex specification, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

After this, we need to restart the Apache web server in order for our changes to be recognized. You can do this by typing this:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.